# On saving a file, how to make eclipse m2e build the current project AND the EAR project that references it?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

Apparently, I can easily configure m2e in Eclipse so that when I save a file, Eclipse will "build" the project with Maven.  I'm not sure what goal it's going to specify.

What I'd really like to know is how to make it not only build the artifact for that single project, but to also run the Maven build for a DIFFERENT project.  For instance, if I have a "app-war" project which my source file is in, and I also have a "app-ear" project that has "app-war" as a dependency, I'd like to see if it's possible on saving a file to first build the WAR, then the EAR, and finally use the appserver-specific protocol to deploy or redeploy the app on a local appserver.

Comment: wouldn't that an overkill ?

Comment: Certainly in general, but I can see that many projects would benefit from this.  In fact, RAD apparently attempts to do this in cooperation with local instances of WebSphere.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook plugin's execution with m2e's lifecycle

```
<pluginManagement>
<plugins>
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
 <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0</version>
 <configuration>
   <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
     <pluginExecutions>
       <pluginExecution>
         <pluginExecutionFilter>
           <groupId>some-group-id</groupId>
           <artifactId>some-artifact-id</artifactId>
           <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
           <goals>
             <goal>some-goal</goal>
           </goals>
         </pluginExecutionFilter>
         <action>
             <!-- here -->
         </action>
       </pluginExecution>
     </pluginExecutions>
   </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```